# Do not match routes outside of subdomain constraint for requests in that subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

From routes.rb:

```
constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
  scope module: 'admin', as: 'admin' do
    resources :subscribers
    root 'dashboard#index'
  end
end

resources :users
root 'dashboard#index'
```

Under current snippet GET admin.domain.xzy/users still triggers users controller action.  I understand that the rules will continue to be parsed until one specifies.  Is there a way to modify this behavior?  Such that for the subdomain constraint, the router will only search within that block.

Answer (score 3):

Why not put the offending line inside another constraint?

```
  constraints(NoSubdomain) do
    resources :users
  end
```

The constraint would look something like this:

```
class NoSubdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    !request.subdomain.present?
  end
end
```